# Stack smashing detected - aborted after updating struct in function by pointer

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct

Running the code, I got "stack smashing detected " - aborted after pointer returned from function (which works correctly - it's allocate structer and initiate it).

```
// global putside the main:

typedef struct {int id; int flight; int chairs;}request,*Prequest;

//calling from main look like:

Prequest p1 = (Prequest)convert_from_buffer_to_struct(buffer);

//the function :

Prequest convert_from_buffer_to_struct(char buffer[]) {

    printf("\nbuffer is:%s",buffer);
    char sid[ID_LONG],sflight[FLIGHT_LONG],schairs[CHAIRS_LONG];
    int id, chairs, flight;
    Prequest p = (Prequest) malloc(sizeof(request));

    if(p == NULL){ printf("\n in converting :struct allocation faild\n");exit(-1);}

    strcpy(sid,&buffer[0]);
    id= atoi(sid); 
    p->id= id;

    strcpy(sflight,&buffer[ ID_LONG + SPACE_LONG ]);
    flight= atoi(sflight);
    p->flight=flight;

    strcpy(schairs,&buffer[ID_LONG + SPACE_LONG + FLIGHT_LONG +SPACE_LONG]);
    chairs= atoi(schairs);  
    p->chairs=chairs;
    return p;
}
```

I have checked the function many times by putting printf after each line to show each result , it works very will,but the error I get after the pointer being returned to the main .

So what do u expect the reason that the two pointers :

```
p (returned from the function),
```

and

```
p1 (defined in main),
```

Why do they led to stack crashing ?

Comment: Can you grant that `strcpy(sid, &buffer[0]);` doesn't copy more than `ID_LONG - 1` characters? Does `buffer` contain 0-terminators? `strcpy()` copies until (inclusive) 0 byte is found. If this is done wrong this would be good for a stack smashing IMHO.

Comment: I tried also:  _strcpy(sid, buffer);_  , but still irrelevant to the stack crash

Comment: Your question is not a [mre]. Please provide a [mre]. Also, why are you copying the strings at all?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `typedef struct {int id; int flight; int chairs;}request,*Prequest;`  It is always a very bad idea to hide a pointer via a `typedef`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char sid[ID_LONG],sflight[FLIGHT_LONG],schairs[CHAIRS_LONG];` and similar statements:  What is `ID_LONG?  What is `FLIGHT_LONG`?  What is `CHAIRS_LONG`? What is `SPACE_LONG`?  We cannot guess, so your code needs to be complete, cleanly compile, etc

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(schairs,&buffer[ID_LONG + SPACE_LONG + FLIGHT_LONG +SPACE_LONG]);`   Buffer is a char array.  So this statement result in an incorrect parameter: `&buffer[...]`   results in the address of some byte that is far into/along the buffer

Comment: how big is the declaration of `buffer[]`?

Comment: what does ` printf("\nbuffer is:%s",buffer);` display on the terminal?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `Prequest p = (Prequest) malloc(sizeof(request));`  in C, the returned type from the heap allocation functions is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(p == NULL){ printf("\n in converting :struct allocation faild\n");exit(-1);}` for ease of readability and understanding, Please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\n in converting :struct allocation faild\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when an error indication comes from a C library function, output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  Suggest using: `perror( "your error message" );

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(sid,&buffer[0]);`  1) Most likely, the length of `buffer[]` is greater than the length of `sid[]`  The result is a buffer overflow and results in undefined behavior

Comment: OT:  this: `strcpy(sid,&buffer[0]);
    id= atoi(sid); 
    p->id= id;`  can be reduced to: `p->id = atoi( buffer );`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `buffer` is bigger array which holds id,flight and chairs in it with only one `null` termination at the end.

You are accessing out of bound for `sid`, `sflight` and `schairs`.

`strcpy` will copy the contents until it reaches `\0` thus accessing out of bound for `src` arguments.

replace

```
strcpy(sid,&buffer[0]);
```

to

```
strncpy(sid,&buffer[0], ID_LONG);
sid[ID_LONG - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: How can you be sure? Your doubt is reasonable (I've the same) but actually the question lacks enough info to be sure.

Comment: @Scheff added the assumption.

Comment: Actually, it's irrelevant how big `buffer` is but it's (unknown) contents is what counts beside of the unknown definition of all these `ID_`s.

Comment: @Scheff I agree, this what we can guess with provided code, let see OP's response.

Comment: actually, I tried to print what he had copied , and it was correct

Comment: after using the  **strncpy(sid,&buffer[0], ID_LONG);sid[ID_LONG - 1] = '\0';** , I got  Segmentation fault , he is aborting  at the same line like before

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason of that , it's the thread which called this functio, it was defined as pointer to refrence to thread, I fixed it ,it works. thnx